# Require specific token to execute a smart contract

Tags: contract-development, tokens

Is it possible to only allow parties that agreed to a smart contract on the Ethereum blockchain to use a specific token for it's executing (e.g. not using Ether but token xxx)?

Comment: You mean as a transaction fee?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do this just with smart contract, since every transaction which changes contract state requires amount of ether to be used.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done but you still have to pay `ether` for the transactions. The mechanism would be

user sends the transaction to the `relayer` with the `token` you want to use as `fee` and the `relayer` will send the `transaction` to the `network` with some transaction fee in ether. The relayer will pay for the transaction fee in ether and will keep the `token` as fee for himself.

These kind of transactions are called `Meta Transactions`. [Here](https://medium.com/@austin_48503/ethereum-meta-transactions-90ccf0859e84) is a good example explaining the process.